# drawing instruction lines in 3d model in sketchup

Tags: sketchup

I am converting one of my apps from using plain instruction images to using the new apple Augmented Reality (AR). For this I am drawing a sketchup model for each instructional image. Everything is working nicely, I have created components (table, balls...) that I can reuse easily.

However, what is the best way to draw the below instruction lines in sketchup?

Additionally, as you can see the app is about snooker, how can I easily make sure that each instructional line is positioned at the height of the center of the balls?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the protractor tool.
[image]

Note the angle I can specify. Draw two of these help-lines from each corner, then use the pen tool to fill in the triangle. [image]

For the additional part. You can select the line you want to edit. Right click and select divide, moving closer to either endpoint of the line would create larger or smaller dividents. [image]

Then, just change color of the line.

Comment: With the instruction lines I mean the white dashed lines in the original 2d image (see picture). How can I draw a dashed line in sketchup?

Comment: ? Its not an answer to my question. How can I draw these dashed instruction likes?